# It has/have to be (to have)

Tags: grammar, verbs, syntactic-analysis

What kind of person **it has to be to have** no doubts about your choice?

Aren't there too many infinitives in one sentence? I'm asking about syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is wrong (and punctuation would help as there is an infinitive phrase):

What kind of person has it to be, to have no doubts about your choice?

"**Has it to be**" can be restated as "**must it be**"

Or the whole thing can be restated as

What kind of person **must it be**, to have no doubts about your choice?

which gives

What kind of person **must it** be, who would have no doubts about your choice?

and an improvement would be:

What kind of person must **they** be, if they have no doubts about your choice?

Comment: I'm guessing that Opie truncated the sentence.  Likely started something like "Tell me what kind of person it has to be to have no doubts about your choice?"  That is perfectly valid (if a bit arcane).

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting your intention correctly, the issue is not the number of infinitives, but rather the sentence's syntactic construction as a whole.

The "person who has no doubts" is the *subject*, their "choice" the *object*. As constructed this is not abundantly clear, particularly because *"it"* is typically used as an impersonal pronoun, and therefore generally reserved for impersonal objects. Indeed, when *it* is used to refer to a person, it tends to be considered derogatory.

A better formulation, I would offer:

What kind of person must *one* be to have no doubts about *their* choice? [Rhetorical.]

What kind of person must *you* be to have no doubts about *your* choice? [Interrogative.]

Formed as such, the answer seems self-evident, in either case.

Comment: The sense of the sentence: what kind of person must one be FOR ME to have no doubts about my own choice. So, if I use your recommendations, will it be correct? 

**What kind of person must one be for you to have no doubts your own choice?**

Answer (score 0):

What kind of person has no doubts about their choices? 
(in the interest of concision)

The issue of gender arises, since we'd prefer to use an impersonal pronoun, such as "What kind of person has no doubts about his choices?" or "What kind of person has no doubts about her choices?", but English has no such non-gendered pronouns-- a serious deficiency  all the more urgently in need of modification in light of "non-gendered" people.

On the other hand, I'm confused about who "person" refers to, who "it" refers to, and who "your" refers to. That is, who is having doubts and who is making choices? The various answers above reveal some differences in understanding that.